# Enable Python to Connect to MySQL via SSH

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I'm using pymysql with Python 3.8 to allow Python to make connections to another MySQL server. I get an error:

```
with pymysql.connect('127.0.0.1', user = '123', password = '123', port = server.local_bind_port) as connection:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

python:

```
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
    import pymysql
    
    
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('76.21.187.192', 2222),
        ssh_username = '123', 
        ssh_password = '123',
        remote_bind_address = ('127.0.0.1', 3306)) as server: 
    
        with pymysql.connect('127.0.0.1', user = '123', password = '123', port = server.local_bind_port) as connection:
            print('OK')
```

How to properly connect to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a with block in python, the object in the with statement gets its **enter** method called, the block inside the with runs, and then the **exit** gets called (optionally with exception info if one was raised). Thus, if you don't have an **enter** defined on your class, you'll see this error.

or else instead of above statement you use :

connection = pymysql.connect('127.0.0.1', user = '123', password = '123', port = server.local_bind_port)